# VBA: Sorting error

Tags: vba, sorting

I have a MISMATCH 13 error when trying to run this macro:

```
Sub dynamicrange()
Dim group_first_row, group_last_row, total_last_row As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dane")

    total_last_row = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Sorting
    ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(total_last_row, 32)).Sort.SortFields.Add Key1:=Range("C2:C" & total_last_row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order1:=xlAscending

End Sub
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Try to change `.SortSortFields ` on `.SortFields ` .

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: I don't know. Check the doc about Sort or SortFields, the Microsoft one is quite good. You'll find some answers here !

Comment: Is `Dane` the active sheet when you run the code?  The cells part of this line is using the active sheet `ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(total_last_row, 32))`  you need to add `ws.` before each instance of `Cells`.

Comment: Also `group_first_row` and `group_last_row` (which you don't use in the code) are declared as variants rather than integer.  Would be better to use long rather than integer - integer can only hold values up to 32,767 so will crash if your total row is on a row number higher than that.